# How to add data behind a login via iframe

Tags: iframe

so I'm working on on a WordPress site, but I want to pull a graph from another site. However, I need to be logged into the website in order to view the graphs/data.

I'm very new to web development; this is a side project I am working on with another newbie in my company. I have some experience and knowledge, but I think this is a bit technical. It seems that I need to use an iframe and link the site, but I'm not quite sure as to how to exactly do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the data you want to include in an iframe is only accessible when logged into another website, then this is not going to be possible, unless the users of your site also log into it. You would need to ask the owners of that site if the data is accessible any other way.

Comment: Alright. Would you happen to know what these other ways of making the data accessible are? I was thinking of finding a way to link a Google Sheets between my site and the one with data.

Comment: No, I don't. I don't know anything about this other site. You'll need to ask them.